# SQL Case Sensitive Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

### Intro

I have a table which is having a column "AccountCode" and other columns. There are few account codes which are same but differs being case-sensitive.
Example:

```
AccountCode   OrderId
ABC           O001
ABC           O002
abc           O003
DEF           O004
```

### Objective

I want a query to have a group by on AccountCode column and get respective count. Expected output should be like

```
ABC      2
abc      1
DEF      1
```

I have tried using COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS but unable to get desired result.

Below query doesn't provide a case-sensitive output

```
select accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, count(OrderId) 
from <<TableName>> 
group by accountCode
```

Comment: `group by accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` should do it

Comment: You are right, I was missing the COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS after Group By clause. I wonder why do we need to define same in Select clause and after Group By clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the COLLATE also on the GROUP BY clause

```
select accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, count(OrderId)  
from <<TableName>>  
group by accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #a
(
AccountCode varchar(10)  , OrderId varchar(10)
)
insert into #a values
('ABC','O001'),
('ABC','O002'),
('abc','O003'),
('DEF','O004')

select accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, count(OrderId) from #a group by accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score -1):

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Temp(AccountCode VARCHAR(100),OrderId VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Temp(AccountCode ,OrderId)
SELECT 'ABC','O001' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC','O002' UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc','O003' UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF','O004'

SELECT AccountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, COUNT(OrderId) FROM #Temp 
GROUP BY accountCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

ROLLBACK TRAN